# How can I access some JSON documents from my AWS lambda function?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am making an AWS lambda function that reads some JSON files and then updates dynamo db based off changes in the file. However, when i package the files with my lambda i cannot access them. I've tried putting them under `/JSONFiles`, `/src/lambda/<MyCodeAndFiles>`, `/src/lambda/JSONFiles`.

In the console when I run the test script and print the directory `/var/task` the only file they're is lib. under `/var/` and under `/` i can't see these files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share screenshot of your deployment package/code structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to keep the files in the function?

A better way might be to use a S3 bucket where you keep all the files and let the lambda function to be able to access to it.

An even better way is to process those JSON messages on-it-fly, using sqs or sns if possible.

I created a small Golang lambda function to parse the CloudWatch logs stream on-the-fly. It might be useful for you - https://applegreengrape.com/posts/lambda-logshipper/

Comment: I agree, but part of the requirements are that the JSON files need to be a part of the package. So it all has to be done on the lambda function.

Comment: which language are you using? For go, you can do something like this:
`
jsonObject:=map[string]string{
    "id":"stufff",
    "id2": "stuffff"
}
`

Comment: I'm using Java! The solutions seems to be to use resources but I need to access a folder not a file.